# Excel VBA VLOOKUP doesn't return Decimal values

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have created a UDF to fetch a number from another workbook, using VLOOKUP.

The expected result is 39.25, but my function returns just 39. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Function getWeight(item As Range) As Long
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    getWeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, Range("'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!Data_TallyItem"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Weight, kg/UOM (BOM)", Range("'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!HDR_TallyItem"), 0), False)
    Exit Function
    
errHandler:
    getWeight = 0
End Function
```

I tried using INDEX/MATCH instead of VLOOKUP, and it also did not return the decimal values. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `Where did I go wrong?` - `As Long`?

Comment: Thank you. I removed it, and the problem is resolved. However, I thought that Long is used for decimal places, isn't that right? Then how... did this happen? Edit: NVM, long is for integers.

Comment: `Long` is the "long" version of an Integer. An Integer in VBA has only 16 bit while a Long uses 32 bit. For Numbers with decimals you need to use `Double`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/data-type-summary .

Answer (score 0):

```
Function getWeight(item As Range)
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    getWeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, Range("'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!Data_TallyItem"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Weight, kg/UOM (BOM)", Range("'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!HDR_TallyItem"), 0), False)
    Exit Function
    
errHandler:
    getWeight = 0
End Function
```